# Prove or disprove that $I= \{a\in R\mid \alpha(a)>\alpha(1_R)\}$ is an ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Prove or disprove:

> Let R be an Euclidean domain, then
>   $I= \{a\in R\mid \alpha(a)>\alpha(1_R)\}$ is an ideal in R.

where $\alpha$ is an Euclidean norm.
So, there must be proved three conditions for being an ideal of R, one of them is
$$\forall a \in I ,\forall r\in R \implies ar\in I$$

Therefore is it sufficient to disprove, if we take $a=x, r=u*x^{-1}$, for some unit  $u\in R$, then $ar=u$, and as far as I know $\alpha(u)=\alpha(1_R)$ for some unit $u$ then $\alpha(u)\not\gt\alpha(1_R)$ which contradicts our definition.

Comment: In that argument you are assuming that $x$ is already invertible.

Comment: You are right, can you show any contradiction then?

Comment: Does your text require that $\alpha(ab) \geq \alpha(a)$ for all non-zero $a,b$?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Silly question: what is $\alpha$? Just some mapping?

Comment: Why "of course"? It is not always the case, and with that requirement  closure under multiplication by elements from the ring is trivial (assuming you actually add $0$ to the set manually, as the requirement does not even make sense for $0$).

Comment: I doubt you'll get far with multiplication, since the general definition of "degree" is honed so that it reproduces the following behaviour of the degree of polynomials: 1) it increases when you multiply by stuff; 2) it does not increase when you sum stuff. However, your set fails to be an additive subgroup in almost every case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry,
 this is meant to be a comment, but I cannot post a comment. I think 
$\alpha$ refers to Euclidean norm. As a hint, what if you let $R$ to be 
some obvious ring and there should be an easy counterexample (if I am 
right). I can give more details if you wish.
EDIT-1: Are you proving for the general case or just searching for a counterexample?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I found a counterexample, I was searching for a counterexample